# a problem on metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

I am reading the book by Burago and Ivanov "A course in metric geometry". I tried to do some problems but have some difficulties. For example, page 66 exercise 3.1.26:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and set $d_{\epsilon}$ to be the maximum metric w.r.t. the covering of $X$ by all balls of radius $\epsilon$ equipped with the restrictions of d. Let $d_{0}(x, y) = sup_{\epsilon > 0}( d_{\epsilon}(x, y))$. Prove that if $d$ is complete, then $d_0$ is the intrinsic metric induced by d.

The problem states that we have to prove that $d_{0}=d_{L}$ where $d_{L}$ is the metric induced by the length structure on the metric space $(X,d)$. I have no difficulties proving that $d_{L}\geq d_{0}$. But what about the other inequality, i.e. $d_{0} \geq d_{L}$. Here I have no idea. Can anyone show me how to use completness to prove this last inequality? Thanks to all of you.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: so far I have that if $d$ is complete then $d_{L}$ is also complete and by $d_{L} \geq d_{0}$ also $d_{0}$ is complete. But how to go on ?

Comment: here is the link for the book: " http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/bbi.pdf "

Comment: does anyone have an idea?

Comment: yes, I also thaught that one could use corollary 2.4.17 ... but how should one apply it? maybe by contradiction?

Comment: or by using the completness of $(X,d_{L})$ ?

Comment: I try to do the following: I assume that $(X,d_{0})$ is not a length metric. Then by Corollary 2.4.17 there exists $\epsilon_{0}>0$ and $x_{0},y_{0}$ such that for all partitions $x_{1},...,x_{N}$ with $d_{0}(x_{i},x_{i+1})<\epsilon_{0}$ we have that $\sum d_{0}(x_{i},x_{i+1}) \geq d_{0}(x_{0},y_{0})+\epsilon_{0}$. Now since $d_{L}$ is a length metric one chooses a partition (bigger than the first one) $x_{1},...,x_{N}$ such that $d_{L}(x_{i},x_{i+1})<\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{2}$ and $\sum d_{L}(x_{i},x_{i+1}) \leq d_{L}(x_{0},y_{0})+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. How to get here a contradiction ??

Comment: how do you mean to use this corollary?

Comment: anyone an idea?